# Is there any way I can add UIKit namespace to the Xamarin forms shared project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a small script that I usually run in XF to check new font names added:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Japanese
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {

        public static void ShowFonts()
        {

            foreach (var fontFamily in UIFont.FamilyNames.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray())
            {
                var fontNames = UIFont.FontNamesForFamilyName(fontFamily);
                if (fontNames.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var fontName in fontNames)
                    {
                        var font = UIFont.FromName(fontName, UIFont.LabelFontSize);
                        if (font != null)
                            Debug.WriteLine("Family: " + fontFamily + " - " + fontName + "  " + font);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var font = UIFont.FromName(fontFamily, UIFont.LabelFontSize);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Family: " + fontFamily + "  " + font);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it used to work okay but now there is a problem as UIKit is not found. Is there a way I can temporarily add this to my shared project or another way that I can run this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not want to add a reference to UIKit to your shared project. Since this is a piece of debugging code, you can easily add this into one of the classes in your iOS project. For instance in your `AppDelegate.cs`:

```cs
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication uiApplication, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
            Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(app);

#if DEBUG
            foreach (var fontFamily in UIFont.FamilyNames.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray())
            {
                var fontNames = UIFont.FontNamesForFamilyName(fontFamily);
                if (fontNames.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var fontName in fontNames)
                    {
                        var font = UIFont.FromName(fontName, UIFont.LabelFontSize);
                        if (font != null)
                            Debug.WriteLine("Family: " + fontFamily + " - " + fontName + "  " + font);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var font = UIFont.FromName(fontFamily, UIFont.LabelFontSize);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Family: " + fontFamily + "  " + font);
                }
            }
        }
#endif

        return base.FinishedLaunching(uiApplication, launchOptions);
}
```

If you add the `#if DEBUG` compiler directive around it, you are also ensured that if only runs whenever you do a debugging build.

Did you also notice the new [Embedded Fonts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/embedded-fonts-xamarin-forms/) feature? That might make it easier for you to use fonts altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

By default Xamarin.Forms will create your shared project in the form of .NET Standard Library. As UIKit is not a part of .NET Standard you can't use it there.

However some time ago you could pick whether you want to use .NET Standard library or shared project for sharing the code. You can still create it manually just it is not available as a part of the default template. Using the shared project for code sharing allows you to use UIKit in it (just mark it properly with #if directive).

Considering should and shouldn't I am aware that many people will say you shouldn't do this. But I would point out that the man who invented Xamarin - Miguel de Icaza said that in the Xamarin team there is ongoing debate on what is better and that he would personally use the shared project. You don't produce the code for should and shouldn't but to make it work and to minimize the long term costs and in every MVVM theory you will read that you shouldn't apply it literary if it can't help you in making your project better.